# npm install keeps failing because of node-libcurl

Tags: node.js, npm, libcurl, npm-install, node-libcurl

whatever module I try to install, I get the error below.

```
npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/node-libcurl/node_modules/abbrev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/node-libcurl/node_modules/abbrev' -> '/home/ubuntu/spryfit-server/node_modules/node-libcurl/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I literally have no idea why it keeps happening, I tried to install the `abbrev` module in node-libcurl directory. and I figured out that dependencies in node-libcurl get deleted automatically everytime I run `npm install`. never had this situation happen, what should I do?